# Cancel button stop working in Liferay 7 CE GA4

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Cancel button in liferay CE GA4 is stop working due to some reason.I am not able find out the root cause of the issue on development environment.
However it working fine on local machine where I have installed the fresh build(liferay-ce-ga4) with all the modules and custom theme(same configuration as development server).
I inspect the cancel button on both the environment and found that on local instance cancel button has anchor tag with href but this tag is missing on development environment cancel button. I have attached the screenshots for more details. 
[image: Local instance cancel button]

[image: Development instance cancel button]

Comment: This looks like a built in Liferay button, thus is not programming related and not a good fit for stackoverflow. If you want to file an issue with Liferay, please do so. If this affects some of your own development, please edit the question to indicate this.

Comment: In addition to Olafs notes I would like to point out that screenshots of code can't be indexed and thus are hard to find by others with the same issue - please include plain code for your next question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your server ip address to following portal-ext.properties.

```
redirect.url.ips.allowed=127.0.0.1,SERVER_IP
```

If you are accessing using domain name. Then you can also try with.

```
redirect.url.security.mode=domain
redirect.url.domains.allowed=<your domain>
```

For me, it work while adding domain name in virtual host setting from control panel.

```
control panel -> Instance Setting -> Virtual host.
```